# making views which merge same exact tables from multiple databases?

Tags: database, postgresql

our db architecture is composed of multiple databases with the same structure

when our users need to access data from some databases, our app has to iterate on each database to retrieve all data then executes some filters, sort, etc.
it's time consuming but we have to keep these databases independant

is there a way to make a super database with views populated by all child databases?

Comment: did you check dblink? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html

Comment: I already use foreign data wrapper but I don't want to link databases (already done)

Comment: This kind of setup is typically better implemented with multiple [*schemas*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html) in one database. Then you can just query them all at once, given the necessary privileges.

Comment: yep but the theory is not always the best solution for real life needs :) anyway I tested an idea based on foreign data wrappers between a master database and some slaves and a view in master with "union all" of the foreign views of each slaves. the POC seems to work but I need to benchmark this method